# Object Mapper making my values to optionals

Tags: swift, mapping, objectmapper

```
struct User: Mappable {

  init?(map: Map) {

  }

  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    token <- map["token"]
    email <- map["email"]
  }

  var token : String!
  var email : String!
}
```

I'm declaring my strings as conditionally wrapped so that I can use directly with out wrapping, but after mapping all my strings to access I need to wrap again?

Why do need to wrap again?

Comment: because you don't know if there was a value in JSON, what should be there? if there is no value and it can not be a nil?

Comment: But what if i Know Json values will be there definitely

Comment: reflecting on reflection https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: So i don't have an option to say my value will definitely exists

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the wrapping if you check the values in the initializer, something like this will work.

```
struct User: Mappable {

    var token: String
    var email: String

    init?(map: Map) {
        guard let token: String = map["token"].value(),
              let email: String = map["email"].value() else {

          print("User should have token and email")
          return nil
        }

        self.token = token
        self.email = email
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        token <- map["token"]
        email <- map["email"]
    }
}
```

Now you can use token and email in your code without wrapping